# Is there a Lens/Optic that can use to dig deeply into multidimensional maps?

Tags: haskell, lenses

I've had a bit of difficulty using Lenses with Maps. I have maps that look like this `Map String (Map String Int)`. These are multidimensional arrays, and I usually set them up with known dimensions. I often want to read and update elements of these Maps, but not add or delete elements.

I want an optic, similar to `ix "k1" . ix "k2"` that allowed me to do the following:

```
myfunc :: Map String (Map String Int) -> ()
myfunc m =
  let m' = m & ix "k1" . ix "k2" %~ (+1)
      v = m ^. ix "k1" . ix "k2"
  in ()
```

Unfortunately, I can't use `ix "k1" . ix "k2"` because the `v = m ^. ix "k1" . ix "k2"` won't compile because `Int` isn't a Monoid. In general, I can't have this Monoid restriction because I  generally hold fairly complex values in my maps (like some complex state ADT). (I'm guessing this Monoid restriction is there so that `ix` can return a default value if the key doesn't exist.) I want an optic without this Monoid restriction and that would just throw a fatal error if I try indexing with a key that doesn't exist. Is it possible to create such a thing on my own?

Comment: Do you mean `(^?)` or `(^?!)`?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:non

Comment: @moonGoose awesome, replacing `^.` `^?!` works for my purposes! I didn't realize I had this degree of freedom.

Comment: You need `Monoid` to combine results of a traversal. `(^?!)` takes only the first result, so there's no need to combine, so no `Monoid` constraint. `(^?)` wraps it in a `Maybe`, as there may in fact be no results at all.